# I am trying to return a result from a function within a function

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have a function that returns JSON data and I wish to access the data globally. I have tried returning the function as a variable and then returning it again.
News still currently returns undefined.

what I would like is for var News to equal the value of results.feed

```
 var News = function (){

      google.load("feeds", "1");



      var foo;
      function initialize() {
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/rss");
        feed.setNumEntries(10);
      //console.log(feed),
        feed.load(function(result) {
         if (!result.error) {
          console.log(result.feed);
          foo = result.feed;
        }

      });
    };

    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    return foo;
  }();
  console.log(News);
```

Comment: Are you saying that it's not returning it? Are you getting errors in your console? You've gotta help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is, that `return foo;` is called, before the request is finished. The JS-engine launches the Request and then goes on without caring of the result. And `foo` isn't filled with the result.

A typical problem with asynchronous requests.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/reference#load) `load()` loads the feeds. After successfully loading the feeds, a callback is called.

```
feed.load(function(result) {
     /* result is accessible only in this scope*/
}
```

E.g. in order to display the data on the page, you have to call the *display()*-Function within the scope of the callback

```
feed.load(function(result) {
     display(result)
}
```

You could (technically) assign the result to a variable:

```
feed.load(function(result) {
     globalvar=result;
}
```

But then you have to maintain different *states* of this variable, since at one point in time it is not set, and at a later point in time it will be set.

There are different ways to deal with this:

1) [Promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

or

2) MVC-Frameworks like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), https://angularjs.org/
where you have models, and *events* when these models are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what web frameworks you are using (this google.* thing for instance) it's rather hard to help in any more detailed way.

However, if I'm guessing, I'd say that like most things in JavaScript this is an asynchronous operation and your function returns before the request has finished completing.

This is the big hurdle of JavaScript, it's not as... Straightforward as other languages, you often have to write callbacks and this is what you should do here.

In your feed.load it takes a function which contains a result, this looks like the callback.

```
feed.load(function(result) {
  if(!result.error) {
    // This will print out the feed (presumably an object).
    console.log(result.feed);
  }
}
```

You have to decide for yourself how best to handle this, at the very least articulate what it is you are trying to achieve rather than just asking for code.